# Local server doesn't work, directly web on local server go to www

Tags: 7

I have a local host and website designed by drupal, I downloaded a website to local host but when I want to open local web directly go to www not to local, please can help me?

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a full URL somewhere in your .htaccess file, in the root directory. Search for `Rewrite` directives.

Comment: I don't mind a downvote, but without an explanation it's irritating.